# Remove the "upload" button from the image field form element in drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, media

As the title suggests I need to remove the upload button from an imagefield form element within D7.

I can't seem to find the element itself within the form array (via hook_form_alter) and I'm just wondering if it needs to be done a different way perhaps.

(I do realise the button can be hidden with CSS but I'd rather not take that option if I can help it.)

Comment: are you trying to remove it so the user can't upload another file into this field?  if so, there might be a better way to deal with this using permissions.

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to remove the upload button on a particular form, much in the same way you would alter the submit button text via a form alter perhaps. So I'd still want the file browse input so users can select a file just not the upload button.

Comment: Ah, so you want the actual upload to happen only when the form is finally submitted, not after the file has been selected I guess.  In any case, in D6 at least, this is all done within the filefield module's widget by theming it with theme_filefield_widget_file() so perhaps you can retheme it yourself.  It's in filefield_widget.inc if you want to take a look at what it's doing.  Or just use CSS :)

Comment: After searching, the upload button is created via: file_managed_file_process() - and annoyingly there doesn't seem to be a way of overriding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in template.php of your theme, and rename the function.

```
/**
 * Implementation theme_image_widget($variables)
 */
function THEMENAME_image_widget($vars){
  unset($vars['element']['upload_button'], $vars['element']['remove_button']);
  return theme_image_widget($vars);
}
```